# FlatFileItemWriter cannot create new file or update existing file

Tags: java, mongodb, csv, spring-batch

[New to SpringBatch] Using Spring Boot, I am trying to create a job which reads names from MongoDB, converts to lowercase, and outputs to CSV file. My reader and processor are working but the writer isn't.

My code is as follows.

Configuration file:

```
package bbye;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.builder.MongoItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineAggregator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import hello.Person;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfigProcessing {


    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    private String readQuery = "{}";

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public MongoItemReader<Person> readMongo(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new MongoItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("mongoDocReader")
                .jsonQuery(readQuery)
                .targetType(Person.class)
                .sorts(sort())
                .template(mongoTemplate)
                .collection("people")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonDocProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonDocProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> writer() {
        /*FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person> writePerson =  new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>();
            writePerson.name("personDocWriter");
            writePerson.resource(new ClassPathResource("PersonExtracted.csv"));
            writePerson.lineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Person>());
            writePerson.shouldDeleteIfExists(true);
            writePerson.build();*/

     FlatFileItemWriter<Person> fileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
     fileWriter.setName("csvWriter");
     fileWriter.setResource(new ClassPathResource("PersonExtracted.csv"));
     fileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator());
     fileWriter.setForceSync(true);
     fileWriter.close();   
     return fileWriter; 
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob(FileUploadNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2(MongoItemReader<Person> reader) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }

    // end::jobstep[]

    public FieldExtractor<Person> fieldExtractor()
    {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Person> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames( new String[] { "firstName",
                                            "lastName"});
        return extractor;

    }


    public LineAggregator<Person> lineAggregator() {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<Person> la = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Person>();
        la.setDelimiter(",");
        la.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor());
        return la;
    }

    public Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort(){
        String firstName = "firstName";
        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortMap = new HashMap();
        sortMap.put(firstName, Sort.DEFAULT_DIRECTION);
        return sortMap;
    }


}
```

Processor file

```
package bbye;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import hello.Person;

@Component
public class PersonDocProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDocProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {
        final String firstName = person.getFirstName().toLowerCase();
        final String lastName = person.getLastName().toLowerCase();

        final Person transformedPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName);

        log.info("Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");

        return transformedPerson;
    }
}
```

Listener

```
package bbye;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FileUploadNotificationListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        System.out.println("===== listening for job - mongoReader - fileWriter ====");

    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        System.out.println("==== file write job completed =====");

    }
}
```

Here Person is a simple POJO. The stack trace with and without manual file creation is as follows:

1. If the file is not present under src/main/resources FlatFileItemWriter does not create a new file and throws

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Could not convert resource to file: [class path resource [PersonExtracted.csv]]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.getOutputState(FlatFileItemWriter.java:399) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.open(FlatFileItemWriter.java:337) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
........
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [PersonExtracted.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

2. If I create the PersonExtracted.csv file manually, the program runs without errors but does not write anything to the file. In fact, a blank file is returned. The stack trace is as below.

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.2.RELEASE)

2018-06-19 11:35:17.663  INFO 25136 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on MyPC with PID 25136 (C:\eclipse-workspace\gs-batch-processing-master\complete\target\classes started by shristi in C:\eclipse-workspace\gs-batch-processing-master\complete)
2018-06-19 11:35:17.666  INFO 25136 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-19 11:35:17.689  INFO 25136 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bb6bea: startup date [Tue Jun 19 11:35:17 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-19 11:35:18.135  INFO 25136 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-06-19 11:35:18.136  WARN 25136 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2018-06-19 11:35:18.282  INFO 25136 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2018-06-19 11:35:18.284  INFO 25136 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-06-19 11:35:18.293  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/eclipse-workspace/gs-batch-processing-master/complete/target/classes/schema-all.sql]
2018-06-19 11:35:18.297  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/eclipse-workspace/gs-batch-processing-master/complete/target/classes/schema-all.sql] in 4 ms.
2018-06-19 11:35:18.518  INFO 25136 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-06-19 11:35:18.552  INFO 25136 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:140}] to localhost:27017
2018-06-19 11:35:18.554  INFO 25136 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1438717}
2018-06-19 11:35:18.723  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2018-06-19 11:35:18.770  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2018-06-19 11:35:18.778  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]
2018-06-19 11:35:18.781  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 3 ms.
2018-06-19 11:35:18.870  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-19 11:35:18.871  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-06-19 11:35:18.873  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-06-19 11:35:18.880  INFO 25136 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 1.357 seconds (JVM running for 2.284)
2018-06-19 11:35:18.881  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2018-06-19 11:35:18.908  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=exportUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
===== listening for job - mongoReader - fileWriter ====
2018-06-19 11:35:18.917  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
2018-06-19 11:35:18.995  INFO 25136 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:141}] to localhost:27017
2018-06-19 11:35:19.022  INFO 25136 --- [           main] bbye.PersonDocProcessor                  : Converting (firstName: ALICE, lastName: WONDERLAND) into (firstName: alice, lastName: wonderland)
2018-06-19 11:35:19.022  INFO 25136 --- [           main] bbye.PersonDocProcessor                  : Converting (firstName: FIRSTNAME, lastName: LASTNAME) into (firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname)
2018-06-19 11:35:19.022  INFO 25136 --- [           main] bbye.PersonDocProcessor                  : Converting (firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE) into (firstName: jane, lastName: doe)
2018-06-19 11:35:19.022  INFO 25136 --- [           main] bbye.PersonDocProcessor                  : Converting (firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE) into (firstName: john, lastName: doe)
2018-06-19 11:35:19.022  INFO 25136 --- [           main] bbye.PersonDocProcessor                  : Converting (firstName: MARK, lastName: WINN) into (firstName: mark, lastName: winn)
==== file write job completed =====
2018-06-19 11:35:19.031  INFO 25136 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=exportUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

2018-06-19 11:35:19.032  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bb6bea: startup date [Tue Jun 19 11:35:17 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-19 11:35:19.033  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-19 11:35:19.034  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-06-19 11:35:19.035  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:141}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
2018-06-19 11:35:19.036  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-06-19 11:35:19.037  INFO 25136 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question. Turns out the writer was working fine but I was looking at the wrong file. 
When using **ClassPathResource** the file gets created and updated under *target/classes* directory. However, I was looking at PersonExtracted.csv under *src/main/resources* directory, which was never updated.

If I specify **FileSystemResource**, the file gets created and updated at specified location.

Comment: Could you please share how did you fix the issue mentioned at `#1` in the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should use FileSystemResource instead of ClassPathResource. Could you please try and let us know.